# SetImage() method removes titleLabel for UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

**My wish is to make centered image(left) and next to it(right) the label.** 
Without setting an image, there was a perfectly centered titleLabel:

```
btnWhatsapp.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
btnWhatsapp.setTitle("WhatsApp", for: .normal)
```

[image: Without setImage()]

Then I added this code to add an image:

```
btnWhatsapp.setImage(UIImage(named: "phoneIcon"), for: .normal)
btnWhatsapp.imageView?.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.6, 0.5)
btnWhatsapp.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

, and this iswhat I got then:
[image: with setImage()]
, so the title disappeared.

Maybe the problem is that image uses more space than its actual size(the size shouldnt take more widht and height than the icon size). I saw this when changed images background(should be this much grey color):

```
btnWhatsapp.imageView?.backgroundColor = .gray
```

[image: with gray background]

I tried to use the `imageEdgeInsets` but it is very hard to calculate it to fit perfectly on every iPhone.
This is the `Attributes inspector` of the button:

[image: Attributes inspector]

Comment: I see this code `btnWhatsapp.imageView?.backgroundColor = .gray`, could you set a value to `button.backgroundColor` ? then I can know button's frame.

Comment: You can clearly see the button frame :) It has a little rounded, black borders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set title and image at once by default, nor position them as you describe.

If you need to have a UIButton, I'd recommend to make a UIView (or possibly horizontal UIStackView) with UIImage and UILabel inside, position them with autolayout, then you can add this view to the UIButton as a subview.

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.frame = viewFrame // This is the desired frame of your custom UIView or UIStackView
button.addSubview(customView)
```

You will be able to position the views easily for all sizes with this approach, but you will probably want to use autolayout in real word app, instead of hardcoded frames.

Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        label.text = "text"
        
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [image, label])
        stack.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50)
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50)
        button.addSubview(stack)
        
        view.addSubview(button)
        
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your button under your controller class like this:

```
let imageButton: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton(type: .custom)
    b.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1)
    b.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    b.clipsToBounds = true
    b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let imageV = UIImageView()
    imageV.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    imageV.tintColor = .white
    imageV.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageV.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "WhatsApp"
    label.textColor = .white
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
    
    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [imageV, label])
    stack.distribution = .fill
    stack.spacing = 4
    stack.axis = .horizontal
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    b.addSubview(stack)
    stack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    stack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    stack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: b.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    stack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: b.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    
    return b
}()
```

Now in viewDidLoad add button and set constraints in your view (in my case on top)

```
view.addSubview(imageButton)
imageButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
imageButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
imageButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
imageButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: This is literally the exact same answer I provided 2 hours before you, but whatever...

Comment: @OndřejPišín I don't see your answer, I see it now and there's some error in it....

Comment: @OndřejPišín none of the answers helps. you both are making new buttons but I am using my button from storyboard. i tried to change some things and adjust your code to my existing button but it looks weird.

Comment: @stackich Hm, storyboard approach should work the same way, try to create a fresh new button and container view (or stackView in my example) as subview in storyboard and if it works, you can build upon that. Otherwise I don't know how to help with the information I have.